# Conditional expectacion on Mutual exclusivity events

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Without making any calculus can you tell which is the expectation (on example `E[A|B]`) on Mutual exclusivity events? And the covariance?

Ex. Dice dropped 100 times event `A: odd numbers` ; `B: even numbers`

Is it Zero?

Thanks,

Comment: You can conditional on an event (formally is the sigma algebra generated by that event), but when you talking about the expectation, it is applied on random variable. So in this case do you mean the indicator of the event $A$ instead? If yes then it just become conditional probability, and as what you expected the probability is zero by definition.

Comment: Yes it's an indicator so you are right it's zero